# Save Variables to Localstorage and then send to Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, variables, local-storage

At first sorry for my bad english but i hope you will understand my request.

Im working on a Phonegap App. User can buy via an payment provider a vip Status. I would like to work with local storage and mysql but im stuck with problems because of missing knowledge of mine. I googled a lot but because everything is on english its really hard for me to learn things.

What i want is, that on the first app start on the phone after download the application generates an random unique username or numeric value and saves it on the local storage as variable. Also it should save a variable called "vip" to the local storage and set it to 0. And it needs to check if the variables are already set, then the application need nothing to do.

These to Variables should be send to an mysql table, lets call it "user".

Example: User Table

```
+---------+-------------+
| username| vip         | 
+---------+-------------+
 A7w893579       0
```

So the variables are saved on the local storage and in the mysql database.
After the user makes an payment over the payment provider the variable "vip" needed to set to 1 and fetch it to the right username and saves the 1 into the vip row for the user on the user table.

And i need any way to do a function like: If the vip status is 1 show in a iframe vip.html on a site. If its 0 show novip.html on the site.

Have you any ideas how i can do that? I read something about Ajax Calls but i dont understand it right. If somebody have a few code snippets i would be very thank full. I dont need full code i just need to read it and try to understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how your view is but you can follow these steps to do what you want.

1. Load Cordova properly when application get started. Fire `onDeviceReady`
2. Calculate your username, any random combination and save them in `localStorage`
3. Send username and vip status via ajax call to your php server
4. Depending upon your server response show user iframe i.e vip.html or novip.html

**Step 1:**
Load all required features of cordova with the help of below code.

```
// this call and loads all cordova function which are required. 
//Device ready is fired when it is loaded successfully.    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
                // Handle what your application wants to do first
                // Save username and vip status, call ajax using to php server
                function onDeviceReady() {
                    var username="calculate username";
                    var vipStatus=0; //or 1
                    }
```

**Step 2:** Store data in localstorage. There are two ways to use localstorage. Native cordova way of doing.

```
// set value
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
// get value back
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

But what i prefer to do directly store in localStorage i dont use key value pair. Its easy to store and access.

```
//store in localStorage
localStorage.vipStatus=0; // or 1
// to get back the value
var Status=localStorage.vipStatus;
```

**Step 3:** Make ajax call to your php server. Refer Jquery Ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) sample code is below

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost:3001/",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: JsonData,
     async: false,
     crossDomain: true,
     success: function(data) {
         alert('success');
     },
     error: function(response, text, err) {
         alert(err);
     }
 });
```

**Step 4:** Display proper page as per vip status

I think you need to implement all the things at the start so you should implement them in `onDeviceReady` as below

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
// Handle what your application wants to do first
// Save username and vip status, call ajax using to php server
function onDeviceReady() {
    // calculate username
    var username = "calculate username";
    // set status
    var vipStatus = 0; //or 1.
    // store in localstorage
    localStorage.vipStatus = vipStatus;
    // set up json i.e send username and vipstatus to server 
    // make ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JsonData,
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
            if (status == 0) {
                // its 0 so show novip.html
                window.location.href = "novip.html";
            } else {
                //its 1 so show vip.html
                window.location.href = "vip.html";
            }
        },
        error: function(response, text, err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okey thank you very much, i will try out tomorrow and give you feedback :).

But it creates everytime on app start a user name and vip status variable or i am wrong? How can i check if the variables are even exists and skip the part?

Greetings.

Comment: Validations you need to implement. We can't provide you whole code. But my answer can help you out in your implementation. Do upvote if it was helpful to you.